# Выравнивание картинок в 1 ряд по горизонтали с переносами <br>

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

Нужно выровнять изображения в 1 ряд, чтобы было все в ровень. А то получается что верхний ряд съезжает вниз из-за переносов `<br>`. Второй и последующие ряды отображаются нормально как надо. Правки могу внести только в CSS.

```css
.pic {
  display: block
}
.pic img {
  float: left;
  margin: 0 5px 10px
}
```

```html
<div class="pic">
  <a href="/"><img src="https://neomaks.ru/lenta/walking_dead_9.jpg" alt="" title=""></a>
  <br>
  <a href="/"><img src="https://neomaks.ru/lenta/Sharp-Objects.jpg" alt="" title=""></a>
  <br>
  <a href="/"><img src="https://neomaks.ru/lenta/boites.jpg" alt="" title=""></a>
  <br>
  <a href="/"><img src="https://neomaks.ru/lenta/AHS_S8_Apocalypse.jpg" alt="" title=""></a>
  <br>
  <a href="/"><img src="https://neomaks.ru/lenta/Preacher.jpg" alt="" title=""></a>
  <br>
  <a href="/"><img src="https://neomaks.ru/lenta/Salvation.jpg" alt="" title=""></a>
  <br>
  <a href="/"><img src="https://neomaks.ru/lenta/elementary-6-sezon-2018.jpg" alt="" title=""></a>
  <br>
  <a href="/"><img src="https://neomaks.ru/lenta/LostInSpace_2018.jpg" alt="" title=""></a>
</div>
```

Comment: Здравствуйте. Нужно выровнять верхний ряд изображений по горизонтали, чтобы они не смещались как в примере. Правки можно внести только в css файл. В html просто убрать лишние переносы BR нет возможности.

Comment: Вопрос перевел. На счет кода я пробовал присвоить родительскому диву ID #pic br {display: none;}, картинки правильно отображались, но появилась новая проблема. Текст, который выше этих картинок также начал отображаться без переносов и первая картинка начиналась там, где заканчивался текст, а это не есть хорошо. Нужно убрать переносы строк только для изображений.

Comment: А зачем вообще с помощью `<br>`, задача такая? А то это геморный способ если честно и никто так не делает в жизни.

Comment: Есть пара сайтов, в которых напарсено несколько тысяч галлерей с фотографиями. Раньше фото отображались в 1 ряд, сейчас в новых шаблонах должны отображаться в 2-3 ряда. Если править html, уйдет очень много времени. Ну если с css не получится, придется убирать как-то лишние переносы вручную. Потому что на автомате они уберутся и из текста

Comment: Интересует вопрос: Почему только в первом ряду изображения отображаются криво? Во втором, третьем и последующих все ровненько. И этот баг на всех браузерах.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Но ранее вы писали, что у вас текст сверху должен быть, в данном методе текст будет строго справа или слева, смотря в какое место он пишется. Если до `img` - тогда слева, после - справа!

```css
.pic {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.pic img {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 5px 10px
}
```

```html
<div class="pic">
  <a href="/"><img src="https://neomaks.ru/lenta/walking_dead_9.jpg" alt="" title=""></a>
  <br>
  <a href="/"><img src="https://neomaks.ru/lenta/Sharp-Objects.jpg" alt="" title=""></a>
  <br>
  <a href="/"><img src="https://neomaks.ru/lenta/boites.jpg" alt="" title=""></a>
  <br>
  <a href="/"><img src="https://neomaks.ru/lenta/AHS_S8_Apocalypse.jpg" alt="" title=""></a>
  <br>
  <a href="/"><img src="https://neomaks.ru/lenta/Preacher.jpg" alt="" title=""></a>
  <br>
  <a href="/"><img src="https://neomaks.ru/lenta/Salvation.jpg" alt="" title=""></a>
  <br>
  <a href="/"><img src="https://neomaks.ru/lenta/elementary-6-sezon-2018.jpg" alt="" title=""></a>
  <br>
  <a href="/"><img src="https://neomaks.ru/lenta/LostInSpace_2018.jpg" alt="" title=""></a>
</div>
```

Comment: Большое спасибо! Заработало! Вопрос решен!!!

Comment: @MichailSotnikov да не за что, поставлю + Александру, я просто не заметил, что он раньше написал ответ(

Comment: @ПавелИгоревич Спасибо)

Comment: @AlexandrTovmach да не за что, я просто открыл полигон и ушел курить, а потом пришел и написал код )) Так что прошу прощения(

Answer (score 5):

```css
.pic {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.pic img {
  margin: 0 5px 10px
}
```

```html
<div class="pic">
  <a href="/"><img src="https://neomaks.ru/lenta/walking_dead_9.jpg" alt="" title=""></a>
  <br>
  <a href="/"><img src="https://neomaks.ru/lenta/Sharp-Objects.jpg" alt="" title=""></a>
  <br>
  <a href="/"><img src="https://neomaks.ru/lenta/boites.jpg" alt="" title=""></a>
  <br>
  <a href="/"><img src="https://neomaks.ru/lenta/AHS_S8_Apocalypse.jpg" alt="" title=""></a>
  <br>
  <a href="/"><img src="https://neomaks.ru/lenta/Preacher.jpg" alt="" title=""></a>
  <br>
  <a href="/"><img src="https://neomaks.ru/lenta/Salvation.jpg" alt="" title=""></a>
  <br>
  <a href="/"><img src="https://neomaks.ru/lenta/elementary-6-sezon-2018.jpg" alt="" title=""></a>
  <br>
  <a href="/"><img src="https://neomaks.ru/lenta/LostInSpace_2018.jpg" alt="" title=""></a>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо. Уже ровно, но все изображения встали в 1 ряд. Как сделать автоматический перенос на следующий ряд? Для примера блок шириной 960px

Comment: Отредактировал ответ

Answer (score 0):

```css
.pic {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
}

.pic > br {
  display: none;
}

.pic {
  margin: 0 5px 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="pic">
  <a href="/"><img src="https://neomaks.ru/lenta/walking_dead_9.jpg" alt="" title=""></a>
  <br>
  <a href="/"><img src="https://neomaks.ru/lenta/Sharp-Objects.jpg" alt="" title=""></a>
  <br>
  <a href="/"><img src="https://neomaks.ru/lenta/boites.jpg" alt="" title=""></a>
  <br>
  <a href="/"><img src="https://neomaks.ru/lenta/AHS_S8_Apocalypse.jpg" alt="" title=""></a>
  <div class="text">
    Какой-то<br>
    Текст
  </div>
  <br>
  <a href="/"><img src="https://neomaks.ru/lenta/Preacher.jpg" alt="" title=""></a>
  <br>
  <a href="/"><img src="https://neomaks.ru/lenta/Salvation.jpg" alt="" title=""></a>
  <br>
  <a href="/"><img src="https://neomaks.ru/lenta/elementary-6-sezon-2018.jpg" alt="" title=""></a>
  <br>
  <a href="/"><img src="https://neomaks.ru/lenta/LostInSpace_2018.jpg" alt="" title=""></a>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое! Этот результат также пригодился на другом сайте, где встречается текст с изображениями вперемешку.